# How to receive user input, manually validate it, and update the data?

Tags: reactjs, database, architecture

This is a question about technology choices for a React app.

Our Leaflet map is served using ReactJS. When we build the app, the layers get rendered using data from a bunch of CSVs, geojsons, etc.. This allows for faster loading, since we have quite a few layers with many data points each.

We want to allow the user to add features to the map by submitting a form on the web app, which would then be manually validated by one of us on the team, before it gets added to the map. We are seeking to automate as much of this process as possible.

What kind of technologies would we need for this to happen? What technology do people use for this "landing page" where the user's data gets sent, as it waits for us to validate it before we add it to the database/files we have locally? Is our current approach going to work with our vision, or do we need to host our data in a database, e.g. sqlite or Firebase?

My understanding so far is that React is static and client-side, so I cannot query a database from it?

Comment: "We want to..." isn't a question, and generally doesn't really lead to a concrete problem or a single true answer.  "What kind of technologies would we need..." is extremely broad, and almost always leads to opinions rather than answers.  Overall, this isn't really focused enough to be answerable in this format.

Comment: Where can I ask for advice on this?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to declare states:

```
const [value, setValue] = usestate('');
const [error, setError] = useState('');
```

To perform validations, you can create a function inside your server :

```
const validateInput = (val) => {
  //...do your check here and return  the data if valid (with 200 response code) or an error with a message what is wrong with 400 code
}
```

Also, you can validate on front end:

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
   //... do checks on `value` state parameter, if all is OK, send request to server, else setError() with reason and show it in some form of alert to user
}
```

Then a basic form:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  // Some Alert Component
  <Alert hidden={!error} value={errror} />
  <input value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}/>
  <button type='submit'></button>
</form>
```

And on the server, you can write a function which first checks and then adds to DB (below code is in node with TS):

```
export const addSongToDB = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  try {
    // Server-side validaiton
    if (!req.body.URL || !req.body.name)
      return next({ status: 400, message: 'Song URL and name are mandatory' });

    const newSong = await db.Song.create(req.body);

    const {
      id,
      name,
      URL,
      posterURL,
      artist,
      album,
      composer,
      genre,
      year,
      playedOn,
    } = newSong;

    return res.status(200).json({
      id,
      name,
      URL,
      posterURL,
      artist,
      album,
      composer,
      genre,
      year,
      playedOn,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    // This next() goes to the error handler of the server
    return next({
      status: 500,
      message: error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

I have created a generic error handler on backend to make lives of front-end devs better:

```
const errorHandler = (
  error: CustomError,
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) =>
  res.status(error.status || 500).json({
    error: {
      message: error.message || 'Oops.. something went wrong!',
    },
  });

export default errorHandler;
```